# ndimage script mis-behaving

Tags: python, scipy, filtering

I have a script that reads in image data, and then iterates over the images with the median filter in scipy.ndimage. From the iteration i create new arrays.

However when i attempt to run the script with

```
run filtering.py
```

The filtering does not seem to work. The new arrays (month_f) are the same as the old ones.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as numpy
from scipy import ndimage
import Image as Image


# Get images 

#Load images

jan1999 = Image.open('jan1999.tif')
mar1999 = Image.open('mar1999.tif')
may1999 = Image.open('may1999.tif')
sep1999 = Image.open('sep1999.tif')
dec1999 = Image.open('dec1999.tif')
jan2000 = Image.open('jan2000.tif')
feb2000 = Image.open('feb2000.tif')

#Compute numpy arrays

jan1999 = numpy.array(jan1999)
mar1999 = numpy.array(mar1999)
may1999 = numpy.array(may1999)
sep1999 = numpy.array(sep1999)
dec1999 = numpy.array(dec1999)
jan2000 = numpy.array(jan2000)
feb2000 = numpy.array(feb2000)

########### Put arrays into a list

months = [jan1999, mar1999, may1999, sep1999, dec1999, jan2000, feb2000]


############ Filtering = 3,3

months_f = []

for image in months:
    image = scipy.ndimage.median_filter(image, size=(5,5))
    months_f.append(image)
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a comment but due to reputation limits I'm not able to write one.

The way you import your modules is a bit strange. Especially "import .. as" with the idential name. I think a more pythonian way would be

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from PIL import Image
```

and then call

```
image = ndimage.median_filter(image, size=(...))
```

When I run your steps with a RGB test image it seems to work.

What does jan1999.shape return?